# While using Super CSV can I get the column number in which there is a validation error?

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I'm using Super CSV for validating a csv file.

I'm getting the row number as `listReader.getRowNumber()` but is there a way by which i can get the column number in which there is a validation mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can. The [SuperCsvException](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/exception/SuperCsvException.html) thrown by Super CSV has a `getContext()` method, which returns the [CsvContext](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/util/CsvContext.html) when the exception was thrown (you'll need a try/catch around the call to `read()`).

This contains lots of useful information, including:

- The line number (starts at 1). This is the actual line number of the file.
- The row number (starts at 1). This is not (always) the same as line number (one row can span multiple lines!)
- The column number (starts at 1)
- The row source (in this case the List of tokenized Strings for each column, before cell processors are applied)

In addition, you can also call the [getUntokenizedRow()](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/AbstractCsvReader.html#getUntokenizedRow()) method of the CsvReader to get the raw untokenized row of CSV.

For example

```
ICsvListReader listReader = null;
try {
    listReader = new CsvListReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILENAME),
        CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

    listReader.getHeader(true); // skip the header

    final CellProcessor[] processors = 
            new CellProcessor[]{new Optional(), new ParseInt()};

    List<Object> row;
    while( (row = listReader.read(processors)) != null ) {
        System.out.println(String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, row=%s",
            listReader.getLineNumber(), listReader.getRowNumber(), row));
    }

} catch (final SuperCsvException e){

    // here's what you're after!
    final CsvContext context = e.getContext();
    System.out.println(String.format(
        "something went wrong on lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, colNo=%s",
        context.getLineNumber(), 
        context.getRowNumber(), 
        context.getColumnNumber()));

} finally {
    if( listReader != null ) {
        listReader.close();
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

After looking at the code you added, it looks like you want to capture the validation exceptions, not just know the column number. If so, you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13646982/1068649).

Comment: I didn't understood what you are trying to say.