# continue to read next line with csvBeanReader even if an exception occured

Tags: csv, supercsv

I' using csvBeanReader to read the row of a csv file. 
When i use the while loop to read the raws, for example:

```
while( (object = csvBeanReader.read(Class.class, getNameMapping(), processors)) != null )
```

if an exception occurred, the program will exit from the loop without analizing the remaining raw. Is there a way to continue to read the next line of file even if an exception is occured in one of the previous?

THanksss!!!!

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13646982/1068649